# Forbidden message on apache when using cron job

Tags: php, apache, file, cron, centos

I develop simple php file which should read xml file,select a part of it and echo it into txt file.it should be done every minutes.
so I made cron job in webmin like this

```
php /home/liveradio/update_current_show.php
```

by user liveradio
but after 20 minutes when I wanna access website following message shown:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (CentOS) Server at liveradio.ir Port 80
```

index file is located in `home/liveradio/liveradio.ir` and my php file is:

```
for ($i = 0;$i < 19;$i++)
{
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://live.liveradio.ir:8000/liveradiomp3_48.xspf");
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        if ($child->getName() == 'trackList')
        {
            foreach($child as $child2)
            {
                if ($child2->getName() == 'track')
                {
                    foreach($child2 as $child3)
                    {
                        if ($child3->getName() == 'title')
                        {
                            $myFile = "liveradio.ir/current.txt";
                            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
                            fwrite($fh, json_encode(array('data',$child3)));
                            fclose($fh);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sleep(3);
}
```

`/home/liveradio/liveradio.ir` contain `.htaccess` file to rewrite url.(wordpress .htaccess file)

Comment: check the owner & permissions of `update_current_show.php`

Comment: the owner is liveradio and permission is 755

Comment: try to run from prompt: `wget "http://live.liveradio.ir:8000/liveradiomp3_48.xspf"` and see if you get the same error